# Why I can't pass values with controllers and to display in scene?

Tags: java, javafx, controller

This is the controller to set text to label.

```
@FXML
private Label label1;

public void two(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("window2.fxml"));
    Scene switchEdit = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    stage.setScene(switchEdit);
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


}

public void initData(String title) {
    label1.setText(title);
}

}
```

This is the controller to get the value needed for the label1. I alreay made an object and call the method on the first controller to pass the value from the textfield.

```
@FXML
private TextField txt;

public void goBack(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent roo = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("window.fxml"));
    Scene chEdit = new Scene(roo);
    Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    controller2 control = loader.getController();
    control.initData(txt.getText());


    stage.setScene(chEdit);
    stage.show();
}


}
```

I already watched multiple tutorials but nothing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load the fxml via the static `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method instead of using the `FXMLLoader` instance to load the fxml.

Change

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent roo = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("window.fxml"));
```

to

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("window.fxml"));
Parent roo = loader.load();
```

Of course this also requires the `fx:controller` attribute to be specified in the root element of `window.fxml`. It's value should be the fully qualified name of your `controller2` class.

PS: Consider adhering to the java naming conventions and use type names starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Thankyou thank you Sir!!! Got it now. Thank you too for advise Sir! I really am a beginner and self taught hahaha.

Comment: @Makoy please remember to accept the answers that helped you.